# Number of set partitions such that at least one partition contains many even numbers

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, set-partition

Let us consider the set of all $n$ bit strings $\{0, 1\}^{n}$. Consider a partition of this set
$\{S_{1}, S_{2}, \cdots, S_{k}\}$ for a fixed $k$ (such that $S_{1} \cup S_{2} \cup \cdots S_{k} = \{0, 1\}^{n}$.)

How many ways can we choose $\{S_{1}, S_{2}, \cdots, S_{k}\}$ (all non-empty partitions) such that there is at least one $i \in [k]$ for which the number of even numbers in $S_{i}$ is exactly $\frac{2}{3}|S_{i}|$?

I know that the number of ways I can choose $k$ non-empty partitions is related to Sterling number's of the second kind. But I cannot incorporate the second constraint (that of one partition containing a certain number of even numbers) into my analysis.

Comment: By "even number" I assume you mean a bit string ending in $0$. Are you looking for an exact formula or an approximation? I wouldn't be surprised if most set partitions have many 3-element subsets, and about $\frac38$ of those subsets would have exactly two even numbers. So the answer might be "asymptotically as many as all set partitions".

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean by an even number. And, approximations or exact formulas would both be nice. Can you elaborate more on your intuition of the approximation, perhaps in an answer?